# Calling Java Web Service Method In A Regular Time Period

Tags: java, web-services, centos7

I have a java web service in centos 7 on tomcat 7, and i use this service to update a database. I need to call its method regulary, example:
createCustomer will called in every 12 hour,
createOrder will called in every 3 minute etc.

How can i write this triger and where this code have run (in same server or something else)

Comment: There are multiple ways:http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html, or you could use newScheduledThreadPool or try http://quartz-scheduler.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can give quartz scheduler a shot. Here you can find more infomation regarding the subject :

http://quartz-scheduler.org/generated/2.2.1/html/qs-all/#page/Quartz_Scheduler_Documentation_Set/_qs_all.1.009.html#

In a nutshell you can define an xml file, stating which task would work on which condition ( or time frame ). In the example below :

```
    <!-- Order Recorder Job -->
    <bean id="orderRecorderJob" class="com.cemgunduz.btcenter.job.OrderRecorderJob"/>
    <bean id="orderTask" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject" ref="orderRecorderJob"/>
        <property name="targetMethod" value="execute"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="orderRecorderJobTrigger"
          class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="orderTask" />
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0/5 * * * ?" />
    </bean>
```

A task is defined named orderTask, which is the execute method in orderRecorderJob.
This task is associated with a cron expression, thereby the trigger is defined. So to sum it all up the example above would trigger execute method of orderRecorderJob class every five minutes as stated on its cron expression ( 0 0/5 * * * ?). More on cron expression syntax :

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger